# Is it possible to shorten the code in PyQt5 by sticking lineEdit in for?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have 7 `lineEdit` blocks, and I want the `textChanged` function to trigger when any of them change, I decided to take the easy route and write them out in order, but now I want to shorten my code.

I wanna shorted this

```
        self.lineEdit_2.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
        self.lineEdit_3.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
        self.lineEdit_4.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
        self.lineEdit_5.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
        self.lineEdit_6.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
        self.lineEdit_7.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
        self.lineEdit_8.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
```

like this

```
        for n in range(2, 8):  #check changes on the all lineEdit units
            self.lineEdit_n.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
```

or like this

```
        for n in range(2, 8):
            self.lineEdit_n.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
            getattr(self, 'lineEdit_n%' % n).textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
```

but it does not work
Thanks for your attention

Comment: Jérôme's answer with f-strings is good. You were almost there. I don't know why you tried  `'lineEdit_n' % n` because it does not mean anything. f-strings are the superior option is general but if you wanted to keep your approach it would be `'lineEdit_%d' % n`.

Comment: better keep data on list `self.lineEdit = []` instead of separated variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Check changes on all lineEdit units
for n in range(2, 9):
    getattr(self, f"lineEdit_{n}").textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)
```

Comment: It does. I think I'd put the lineEdits in a list rather than relying on the name like this. Up to you.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it.
```list = ["lineEdit_2", "lineEdit_3", "lineEdit_4", "lineEdit_5", "lineEdit_6", "lineEdit_7", "lineEdit_8"]
for i in range list:
    self.i.textChanged.connect(self..textChanged)
```
like that?

Comment: Sort of, but not as strings. It really depends on the whole code, anyway. There may even be better ways to group them in the first place, I don't know.

Comment: @AlmazIslamov `self.lineEdits = [getattr(self, f'lineEdit_{n}') for n in range(2, 9)]` then `for lineEdit in self.lineEdits: lineEdit.textChanged.connect(...)`, but that's only useful if you need to cycle through those line edits again somewhere else in your code. Note: `list` is a protected word, you shouldn't use it as a variable name.